# MySQL: Stored procedure with variable DATE_ADD intervals

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a MySQL sproc that will copy certain table rows based on the value of one field, `rwo_frequency`. For example, if `rwo_frequency` = 2, then the date interval is one week, and my statement would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (start_date, <other columns>)
SELECT DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS start_date, <other columns>
FROM table
WHERE start_date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
AND rwo_frequency = 2;
```

So, if `start_date` for a record = '2021-06-04', then that record will be copied on 2021-06-11 and given that date as the start date.

Where I'm stuck is how to express `rwo_frequency` and the time interval for DATE_ADD as variables so that the sproc covers all values for `rwo_frequency`. So, if the frequency were monthly (`rwo_frequency` = 3), then the DATE_ADD interval would automatically be 'INTERVAL 1 MONTH'. How can I achieve this in the body of my sproc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [CASE expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case) to make the right side of that comparison a different value for each respective value of rwo_frequency.

```
INSERT INTO table (start_date, <other columns>)
SELECT DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS start_date, <other columns>
FROM table
WHERE start_date = CASE rwo_frequency
    WHEN 2 THEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
    WHEN 3 THEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) 
    ...
    END
```

If rwo_frequency does not match any of the cases, and you don't write an `ELSE` case, then result of the whole expressions is NULL.

Comment: Thanks. This works in both places where I have to do a DATE_ADD. Great solution.